# Не удается инициализировать COM Security в модуле DLL

Tags: c++, windows, com

Пытаюсь инициализировать COM security стандартным методом:

```
hres = CoInitializeSecurity(
    NULL,
    -1,                          // COM authentication
    NULL,                        // Authentication services
    NULL,                        // Reserved
    RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT,   // Default authentication 
    RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, // Default Impersonation  
    NULL,                        // Authentication info
    EOAC_NONE,                   // Additional capabilities 
    NULL                         // Reserved
);

if (FAILED(hres))
{
    MessageBoxA(0, "Failed Initialize S", "s2", MB_OK);

    CoUninitialize();

    //return 1;                  // Program has failed.
}
```

Код исполняется в модуле DLL и возвращает ошибку. Но при запуске отдельно от модуля в моем приложении.EXE , такой проблемы не возникает.

Не пойму, как правильно следует это проделывать внутри библиотеки. Нужно ли подключать через `DllMain` или как-то по другому?

Comment: Какой код возвращаемой ошибки?

Comment: `Однако никаких проблем при обращении к библиотеке из EXE-приложения не возникает` — значит уровня безопасности, создаваемого COM по умолчанию, достаточно для доступа к объектам, реализуемым библиотекой.

Comment: @Arhad  - вы по-моему не поняли, я пытаюсь вызвать ComSecurity из .DLL которая подключена к приложению(К нему я вообще никакого доступа не имею), мой модуль это своего рода экстендер. Я тестировал COM инциализацию на полностью  моем приложении и оно нормально все производило. На сколько я понял, два этих уровня COM Intialize И Com Secutiry производит само приложение(К которому  у меня нету доступа), но в любом случае на инциализации iCoCreateInstance, так же возвращает ошибку.

Answer (score 1):

В комментариях было выяснено, что контроля над приложением, загружающим библиотеку, нет.

Тогда попробуйте вызвать [`CoUninitialize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms688715(v=vs.85).aspx) перед `CoInitializeSecurity` для отмены настроек безопасности, заданных этим приложением ранее.

*Однако, этот метод является, по сути, грязным хаком, а следовательно, потенциально способен нарушить работу как самого приложения, так и всех COM библиотек, уже загруженных до вызова `CoUninitialize`. Поэтому не стоит бездумно применять его без предварительной проверки на работоспособность.*

Comment: =) Зачем вы изменили суть вопроса,я же не говорил что у меня библиотека обращается к родному приложению, я сказал что при запуске отдельно от библиотеки в моем приложении(такой проблемы не возникает) А на счет CoUninitialize - Других  методов нету ? - Мой код по сути достает информацию по железу через `IWbemClassObject ( "Win32_NetworkAdapter ", L"DeviceID")`

Comment: @LighFusion, спасибо за прояснение. Фраза `Код исполняется из модуля .DLL` звучала двояко. Исправьте её, пожалуйста.

Comment: я то изменил, а решить то как это эту проблему можно ? Ну или получать информацию по железу - через что то другое ? Хотя это самое простое.

Comment: @Arhard не как  CoUninitialize - не помогло, приложение просто крашится. Код ошибки 800401f0